# TypeError: 'QuerySet' object does not support item assignment when creating an object in Django

Tags: python, django

I get a " TypeError: 'QuerySet' object does not support item assignment " error message when trying to create an object in Django.
Here is my code:

```
for ing in ingredient_list:
        print(ing['name'])
        target = Ingredient.objects.filter(name=ing['name'], brand=ing['brand'],price=ing['price'],igd_type=ing['igd_type'])
        # If there are no ingredient, create ingredient. 
        if len(target) == 0:
            temp = 0
            print(ing['quantity'])
            tempPicture = "carrot.png"
            price = ing['price_normalized'] if ing['price_normalized'] != 0 else ing['price']
            normPrice = 0 if (ing['price_normalized'] or ing['quantity']==0) else ing['price']/ing['quantity']
            quantity = float(ing['quantity'])
            target[0] = Ingredient.objects.create(name=ing['name'], brand=ing['brand'], 
            price=price, 
            igd_type=ing['igd_type'], 
            quantity=quantity,
            price_normalized=normPrice,
            picture=tempPicture
            ) 
            target[0].save()
                            
            print(target[0])
```

I get the following error:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/recipe/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/virtual-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/virtual-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/backend/project/views.py", line 330, in recipe_post
picture=tempPicture
TypeError: 'QuerySet' object does not support item assignment
```

I get the error at picture. Why can't I assign??
I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: Caould you please mention the detailed error log. Exactly at which line you got the error

Comment: change target[0] to target.

Comment: @yogendramaarisetty 
I added the error log!

Comment: @Meet I think this fixed it!! Thank you so much!

Comment: @juimdpp when your target length is zero you cannot access the 0th index, It throws List index out of range exception. I just want to make sure that, do you want to create an ingredient if it doesn't exist else you'll update it?